# How do I add an item to Windows Explorer's "New" context menu which opens a window?

Tags: c#, windows, explorer, shell-extensions

When you right-click inside a folder on Windows, there is a "New" option in the context menu, which allows you to create various types of files.

I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu), which shows how to add an item to this context menu which simply creates a blank file of the given type, without prompting the user.

What I would like to do is create an item which first opens a window, and then creates a file using data entered into that window. The "New > Contact" option acts just how I would like my custom option to act. When the option is selected, it opens a window prompting for information, which is then used to create a contact file.

[image: Contact option in context menu]
[image: Contact info dialog]

How can I create a new item inside this context menu which opens a window like this? I will use C# and Windows Forms to create the program displaying the window; how will I be able to detect which folder was actually right-clicked when the user clicks "OK" on my window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the command value:

[image: Screenshot]